# JMockit - How to verify a method was invoked on a local varaible

Tags: java, jmockit

This is the code I am trying to test with JMockit:

```
public void unitUnderTest() {
  doSomething();
}

private void doSomething() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.setExtraFooness("its extra fooness");
  ...
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to verify that `foo.setExtraFooness("its extra fooness");` was called?

Comment: No, because it is a real object. It would have to be mock in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always verify calls on mocked methods:

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(@Mocked Foo foo) {
    new ClassUnderTest().unitUnderTest();

    new Verifications() {{ foo.setExtraFooness("whatever"); }};
}
```

That said, it's generally better to avoid mocking when you really want to verify *state*. If the `foo` object can be obtained from the object under test, then the test should simply write a conventional assertion to verify its state.

Comment: Apart from making foo final, it worked like charm!! Thanks Rogerio.